# How to handle async require differently?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, constructor, async-await, require

This is an extension of another issue I had with as async constructor that I solved.

All the code below works correctly.

Here is an example of a class with an async constructor of sorts.
I know there is no such thing as an async constructor  in JavaScript.

```
class loginPage {
    constructor(page) {
        return (async () => {
            this.singleElement = await page.$('.asd')
            this.arrayOfElements = await page.$('.qwe')
            return this
        })()
    }
}
module.exports = loginPage
```

Here is how I access the elements in the constructor from another file.

`const loginPage = async () => new (require('../loginPage.js'))(page)`

Here is how I call the elements to use them inside of an async function.

```
(await loginPage()).singleElement
(await loginPage()).arrayOfElements[0]
```

Because of the async/await, I have to call the elements as functions().

I'd like to find a way to call them as variables.

Then my element calls would look like this->

```
await loginPage.singleElement
await loginPage.arrayOfElements[0]
```

I know the issue is because of the way I am doing the, "require" line.

I tried wrapping all the code in the file like this->

```
(async () => {
    const loginPage = new (require('../loginPage.js')(page)
})()
```

to move the async up a level so I could call the elements as variables.

It seemed to work until I ran the code.

I'm getting errors related to the, "(page)" that's passing through the, "require" line.

It doesn't seem to be properly passing, "(page)" anymore.

"(page)" ends up being undefined or any of the methods like, "page.$" are not known.

I've also tried moving the, "new" back to the class file.

I just can't get this to work as a variable???

Any ides?

Comment: Calling `require` inside an async function won't make it asynchronous. `require` always blocks the main thread. Use the `fs` module instead.

Comment: why make an async function that never uses await in the first place

Comment: I'm not sure why it needs the async on the require line without an await inside?  If I don't have the async it won't execute???

Comment: I'm not sure how I would implement the fs module to help with my issue?

Comment: I tried this-> const tbl = require('../tables.po.js')
var tables = new tbl(page)  No luck I get, "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation"

Comment: I tried adding, "this.page" and I think it went a little farther.  The new error is, " UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '$' of undefined"

Comment: The problem is that, "page" is defined inside of an async function below the, "var tables = new tbl(page)" so it is undefined at the time of instantiation. "page" has an await so it must be in an async function.